# filter look up in dialog

Tags: dialog, x++, axapta

I Have created a dialog in a class, the dialog method is as below

```
static void dialog(Args _args)
{
Dialog              dialog;
DialogField         dialogFieldCurrentState;
DialogField         dialogFieldNewState;
CustInvoiceTable    custInvoiceTable;


;

custInvoiceTable = _args.record();



dialog                  = new Dialog("Change State");
dialogFieldCurrentState = dialog.addField(TypeID(State_LT),"Current State: ");
dialogFieldCurrentState.value(custInvoiceTable.State);
dialogFieldCurrentState.enabled(false);
dialogFieldNewState     = dialog.addField(TypeID(State_LT),"New State: ");

if (dialog.run())
{
    custInvoiceTable.State =  dialogFieldNewState.value();

}

}
```

in my dialog there are two fileds `Current State` and `New State` .Now when i select the `New State` the list of all 
states is displayed(irrespective of country) which i dont want. Only the states respective of country has to be shown 
in the lookup
. I need to make use of a filter something like e.g. `while select while select AddressState
            where addressState.CountryRegionId == custInvoiceTable.CountryRegionId;` so that only states which 
are related to a country is shown.

State_LT here is an string EDT (where i put in the relation of State_LT) State_LT == AddressState.StateId

IN AdressState there is a method lookupStateId(), How to call it from a dialog(code above)
?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am answering to your last question: "IN AdressState THERE IS A METHOD lookupStateId(), HOW TO CALL IT FROM A DIALOG(code above) ?" - by the way writing in capital letters doesn't help people understand your point better.

It is not clear why your `dialog` is a static method, anyway you'd need the following.

Let's say your ClassDeclaration looks something like this:

```
class TestClass1 extends RunBase
{
    Dialog      dialog;
    DialogField dialogFieldCurrentState;
    DialogField dialogFieldNewState;
    // etcetera
}
```

Your `dialog` is something like this:

```
public Object dialog()
{
    ;

    dialog = super();

    dialogFieldCurrentState = dialog.addField(TypeID(AddressStateId),"Current State: ");
    dialogFieldCurrentState.enabled(false);
    dialogFieldNewState     = dialog.addField(TypeID(AddressStateId),"New State: ");
    dialogFieldNewState.lookupButton(FormLookupButton::Always);     // If needed

    return dialog;
}
```

To implement a lookup the way you want it you need to do two things. First, open the dialog, right click on the New State, click Setup, and check the control's System Name. If for example it is **Fld2_1** then you need to create the following method:

```
void fld2_1_lookup()
{
    Object control = dialog.formRun().controlCallingMethod();
    ;

    AddressState::lookupStateId(control, dialogFieldNewState.value());
}
```

Second, it is necessary to override the following method:

```
public void dialogPostRun(DialogRunbase _dialog)
{
    super(_dialog);

    _dialog.dialogForm().formRun().controlMethodOverload(true);
    _dialog.dialogForm().formRun().controlMethodOverloadObject(this);
}
```

That should do the trick. I haven't done it for a while but I don't think I forgot something.

Comment: Thanks 10p once again and yeah i agree to you with the CAPS, sorry :)

Comment: i have added pack/unpack, run method to the class and it works good. By the way why we need pack/unpack here? Is that necessary? Also i want the state selected in other form to be passed into this(dialog) currentState field...

Comment: Please check page 167 of Inside Microsoft Dynamics AX 4.0: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/5/8/258c8894-b94a-4a87-81ea-4dbb9776f8f2/622579ebook.pdf

Comment: thanks a tonn! one thing for sure..if i know AX its coz of You guys and SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Example of looking up customer in dialog:

For example, to have a customer choice dropdown in the dialog,

- In report class declaration method --->

  DialogField         CustomerDlg;
    CustAccount          customer;

  - In the reports dialog method: ----->

  dialog.addGroup("Customer");
  CustomerDlg     = dialog.addField(typeid(CustAccount));
  CustomerDlg.value(customer);

  - In the getFromDialog method: ---->

  ...
  customer    = CustomerDlg.value();