# Create a lookup filter for a dialox in Dynamics AX 4.0

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, x++, axapta

I'm trying to create a custom lookup filter in a dialog in AX.

I've followed the instructions in this post [x++ filter lookup in dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632147/filter-look-up-in-dialog) and am getting a Stack Trace error -- FormRun object not initialized -- when I'm run my code.

What I am trying to do is filter the lookup() for the ConfigId EDT based on the selection from the ItemId EDT. I have the custom lookup() ready to go and working properly, I just can't get it called from my dialog box.

```
public Object dialog(DialogRunbase _dialog, boolean _forceOnClient)
{
    DialogRunBase   dialog;
    ;

    dialog = super(_dialog, true);

    dialog.caption('@RID2885');

    dfItem = dialog.addField(typeid(ItemId));
    dfInventLoc = dialog.addField(typeid(InventLocationId));
    dfReplaceCost = dialog.addField(typeid(PdsCost));
    dfItemConfig = dialog.addField(typeid(ConfigId));
    dfColorId = dialog.addField(typeid(InventColorId), '@RID101');

    return dialog;
}
```

Here's the call to the lookup():

```
void Fld_7_lookup()
{
    Formrun fr = this.dialogModify().parmDialog();
    Object control = fr.controlCallingMethod();    
    ;

    ConfigTable::lookupConfigIdSimple(control, dfItem.value());    
}
```

And this is where it keeps getting the Stack Trace error:

```
public void dialogPostRun(DialogRunbase _dialog)
{
    ;
     super(_dialog);
    **_dialog.formRun().controlMethodOverload(true);** // Causes Stack Trace error
    _dialog.formRun().controlMethodOverloadObject(this);       
}
```

I have tried multiple configurations with the dialog box. When the code reaches that point, it still has information passed in from the dialog() method, but when it goes to get the FormRun, that object is blank.

Could someone please help me understand why there is no FormRun object associated with the DiaglogRunBase that is passed-in?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting no runtime error with your code.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong somewhere else, then. I'm not getting that FormRun to be valid.

Comment: Maybe you're calling dialogPostRun manually or doing something else wrong? Can you provide the code that you're using to open the dialog or any other piece of code that might be relevant to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Mayby you should call `super(_dialog)` last in the `dialogPostRun` method.

Have a look on a [similar solution](http://msdax.blogspot.com/2007/08/overriding-method-for-control-in-dialog.html) and [one more](http://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/f/33/p/29347/50080.aspx).

Comment: I've tried that, too, and I still get the error. I've even tried not including the call to super(), but I still get the Stack Trace error. I've seen those links before, too, but they haven't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see if your class is set to run at "Called From"?

Here is an example code for overriding the modified method. Maybe lookup has the same requirements:

```
public void dialogPostRun(DialogRunbase _dialog)
{
// Must be overriden to enable overriding modified method
;
    _dialog.dialogForm().formRun().controlMethodOverload(true);
    _dialog.dialogForm().formRun().controlMethodOverloadObject(this);
    _dialog.formRun().controlMethodOverload(true);
    _dialog.formRun().controlMethodOverloadObject(this);

    super(_dialog);
}
```

And for the custom method:

```
boolean Fld2_1_modified()
{
    FormStringControl c = dialog.formrun().controlCallingMethod();
    boolean ret;
    ;

    ret = c.modified(); // Super() Call the FormControl ->modified

    dlgCustomField.value(MyClass::someMethod(dlgCustomField.value())); // example

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my class was already set to run at "Called from". There's some other code here that does the same thing and it works. I've copied that code and just replaced with my variables, and it STILL doesn't work. Why it has a null FormRun is beyond me. It shouldn't. It's even null when I come into the DialogPostRun method. The dialog itself isn't, but the dialog's FormRun is. Shouldn't that be set when the dialog is created?